# Access an Array Item by index in AWS Dynamodb Query Results "Items" in Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, dynamodb-queries

I have this dynamodb:Query in my step function:

```
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:dynamodb:query",
  "Next": "If nothing returned by query Or Study not yet Zipped",
  "Parameters": {
    "TableName": "TEST-StudyProcessingTable",
    "ScanIndexForward": false,
    "Limit": 1,
    "KeyConditionExpression": "OrderID = :OrderID",
    "FilterExpression": "StudyID = :StudyID",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":OrderID": {
        "S.$": "$.body.order_id"
      },
      ":StudyID": {
        "S.$": "$.body.study_id"
      }
    }
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.processed_files"
}
```

The results comes in as an array called `Items` which is nested under my `ResultPath`
`processed_files.Items`:

```
{
  "body": {
    "order_id": "1001",
    "study_id": "1"
  },
  "processed_files": {
    "Count": 1,
    "Items": [
      {
        "Status": {
          "S": "unzipped"
        },
        "StudyID": {
          "S": "1"
        },
        "ZipFileS3Key": {
          "S": "path/to/the/file"
        },
        "UploadSet": {
          "S": "4"
        },
        "OrderID": {
          "S": "1001"
        },
        "UploadSet#StudyID": {
          "S": "4#1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "LastEvaluatedKey": {
      "OrderID": {
        "S": "1001"
      },
      "UploadSet#StudyID": {
        "S": "4#1"
      }
    },
    "ScannedCount": 1
  }
}
```

My question is how do i access the items inside this array from a choice state in a step function?
I need to query then decide something based on the results by checking the item in a condition in a choice state.
The problem is that since this is an array I can't access it using regular JsonPath (like with Items.item), and in my next step the choice condition does NOT accept an index like `processed_files.Items['0'].Status`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer was so simple all you need to do is use a number instead of string for the array index like this.

`processed_files.Items[0].Status`

I was originally mislead by an error I received which said that it expected a ' or '[' after the first '['. I mistakenly thought this meant it only accepts strings.
I was wrong, it works like any other array.

I hope this helps somebody one day.